# python no errors but my scraper is coming back blank

Tags: python, web-scraping

It keeps returning blank info and I can't figure out why no errors or anything. I've been trying for hours to look things up and test different things out but still nothing. when I run the product info and get page they work just fine alone but my main function won't return any info.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

agent = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"}
def get_page_link(url):
    r=requests.get(url, headers=agent, timeout=3)
    sp=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    baseurl="https://weedmaps.com"
    links=sp.select("#menu-tab-wrapper div.styles__NameRatingWrap-j5iyiv-15.eaLQmf > a:nth-child(2)")
                       #menu-tab-wrapper > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.styles__NameRatingWrap-j5iyiv-15.eaLQmf > a:nth-child(2)
    return [baseurl+link.attrs['href'] for link in links]
    
def product_data(url):
    r=requests.get(url,headers=agent,timeout=3)
    sp=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    product={
        'Title:' : sp.select_one("#content > div.content-wrapper__ContentWrapper-ljfebg-0.efqrNq > div > div > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.src__Flex-sc-1sbtrzs-1.bQaUiS.eSfsMV > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.jvkycj > div > h1").text,
        'Brand:' : sp.select_one("#content > div.content-wrapper__ContentWrapper-ljfebg-0.efqrNq > div > div > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.src__Flex-sc-1sbtrzs-1.bQaUiS.eSfsMV > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.jvkycj > div > div.styled-components__ProductCategoryBrand-sc-1fbw3xt-6.hTUCiL > a").text,
        'Price:' : sp.select_one("div styled-components__Price-sc-1fbw3xt-15.lbyswm"),
        'Pick_up_location:' : sp.select_one("#content > div.content-wrapper__ContentWrapper-ljfebg-0.efqrNq > div > div > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.src__Flex-sc-1sbtrzs-1.bQaUiS.eSfsMV > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.jvkycj > div > div.styled-components__DeliveryOrPickupWrapper-sc-1fbw3xt-13.bgLZRl > div:nth-child(4) > label > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.cLejZl > span").text,
        'Obj_type:' : sp.select_one("#content > div.content-wrapper__ContentWrapper-ljfebg-0.efqrNq > div > div > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.src__Flex-sc-1sbtrzs-1.bQaUiS.eSfsMV > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.jvkycj > div > div.styled-components__ProductCategoryBrand-sc-1fbw3xt-6.hTUCiL").text,
            }    
    return(product)  
def main():
    distance=input("Miles: ")
    results=[]
    for x in range(1,10):
        urlz=f'http://www.weedmaps.com/search?entryType=home%20page%20product%20card&filter%5BboundingRadius%5D={distance}mi&page={x}'
        urls=get_page_link(urlz)
        productinfo=[product_data(url) for url in urls]
        results.append(productinfo)
    return results

print(main())
```

this is what I keep getting returned with

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Looks like `productinfo` is empty because `urls` is empty. `urls` can be empty iff `links` in `get_page_link` is empty.

Comment: I'm not understanding from what I've learned it's not empty urlz is the URL it's using and going off of and than its going into the get_page_link and adding urlz into urls function and then product info has the product data  with the url with the for url in urls or is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By debugging your code, it seems that `#menu-tab-wrapper div.styles__NameRatingWrap-j5iyiv-15.eaLQmf > a:nth-child(2)` is not found on the page by `BeautifulSoup`. Consequently, `links` is empty.

I tried this with `requests_html` as well, and the same problem occurred. The website you are trying to scrape is most probably dynamic, so you'll need to load the javascript before scraping. In `requests_html`, you can do that by calling `.render()` method. You could find a similar function for `BeautifulSoup`.

More simply put, the website does not have every page with different distance and pages stored in their servers, that would be extremely inefficient, and they generate the HTML on-demand using js and you would need to load the page like a browser does(so that you can see the different results) rather than just scraping the static HTML of the page, which is unpopulated.

Comment: thanks, I guess I need to learn about this but it pulled the info just returned a bunch of none now but it's a step forward thanks.